# Creating a simple image gallery

Tags: jquery

I'm currently learning jQuery (so please bear with me :) and trying to create my own simple image gallery

Here is my html code :

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" class="thumb" data-title="This is Title 1 " data-desc="Description 1 goes here" data-url="http://jsfiddle.net" data-large="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/" data-close="<span>x</span>"/>   
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" class="thumb" data-title="This is Title 2" data-desc="Description 2 goes here" data-url="http://jsfiddle.net" data-large="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/" data-close="<span>x</span>"/>

<div class="overlay"></div>
```

Here's the jquery

```
$(document).on('click', '.thumb', function()
{
    var data_title = $(this).data('title');
    var data_desc = $(this).data('desc');
    var data_url = $(this).data('url');
    var data_close = $(this).data('close');
    $('.overlay').html('<div class="inner">' + data_title + data_desc + data_url + data_close+ '<img src="data_large" />' + '</div>' ).fadeIn( "slow", "linear" );
});
$(document).on('click', '.overlay span', function()
{
$('.overlay').fadeOut();
});
```

and here's the css

```
.overlay {
    display:none;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    top:0;
}
.inner {
    border:1px solid #fff;
}
.show {
    display:block;
}
.hide {
    display:none;
}
.overlay span {
    background:#333;
    color:#fff;
    position:absolute;
    right:10px;
    top:10px;
    padding:20px;
}
```

The code runs good but I face two problems. The first one is the big image doesn't show up when the overlay layer is opened (please see [this image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2nb33cmf1qlzqvx/dwhfl.jpg)) and the second one, in **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WSpZg/9/)** the overlay layer is running properly but when I try it on my computer by local html, the overlay layer show up multiple times.

Any can help me?

Thank you

Comment: I didn't see an element corresponding to the selector '.overlay span' in your html

Comment: its data-close="<span>x</span>"

Comment: @zoora, there was no data large var, please check updated version: http://jsfiddle.net/WSpZg/10/

Comment: omg, my bad thanks @nevermind. How about the second problem, does my jquery implementation is correct?

Answer (score 1):

For your first problem create image element first

```
         img = $('<img src="'+data_url+'"/>');
```

Then append this element to your overlay.

```
  $('.overlay .inner').append(img);
```